# How to use function returning Oracle REF_CURSOR in a procedure

Tags: oracle, plsql, procedure

I have to write an Oracle procedure which should invoke an Oracle function returning REF_CURSOR. The function is declared like that

```
FUNCTION "IMPACTNET"."TF_CONVERTPARA" (PARASTRING IN NVARCHAR2) RETURN SYS_REFCURSOR
AS
  c SYS_REFCURSOR;
BEGIN
    OPEN c FOR         
        SELECT SUBSTR(element, 1, INSTR(element, '|') - 1)     as key,
               SUBSTR(element, INSTR(element, '|') + 1, 99999) as val
        FROM (
            SELECT REGEXP_SUBSTR(PARASTRING, '[^;]+', 1, LEVEL) element          
                FROM dual      
                CONNECT BY LEVEL < LENGTH(REGEXP_REPLACE(PARASTRING, '[^;]+')) + 1
             );
    RETURN c;     
END;
```

Can you tell me what I need to write in order to invoke the function from within my procedure? I'd like to insert all the returned values (shaped a table with two columns) into a rational table.

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something along the lines of this should work (obviously, I'm guessing about table names and column names and the exact logic that you're trying to implement)

```
CREATE PROCEDURE some_procedure_name
AS
  l_rc  SYS_REFCURSOR := impactnet.tf_convertpara( <<some string>> );
  l_key VARCHAR2(100);
  l_val VARCHAR2(100);
BEGIN
  LOOP
    FETCH l_rc
      INTO l_key, l_val;
    EXIT WHEN l_rc%notfound;

    INSERT INTO some_table( key_column, val_column )
      VALUES( l_key, l_val );
  END LOOP;
END;
```

As Ollie points out, it would be more efficient to do a `BULK COLLECT` and a `FORALL`.  If you're just dealing with a few thousand rows (since your function is just parsing the data in a delimited string, I'm assuming you expect relatively few rows to be returned), the performance difference is probably minimal.  But if you're processing more data, the difference can be quite noticeable.  Depending on the Oracle version and your specific requirements, you may be able to simplify the `INSERT` statement in the `FORALL` to insert a record rather than listing each column from the record individually.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE some_procedure_name
AS
  TYPE key_val_rec 
    IS RECORD( 
         key  VARCHAR2(100),
         val  VARCHAR2(100)
    );
  TYPE key_val_coll
    IS TABLE OF key_val_rec;

  l_rc   SYS_REFCURSOR := impactnet.tf_convertpara( <<some string>> );
  l_coll key_val_coll;
BEGIN
  LOOP
    FETCH l_rc
      BULK COLLECT INTO l_coll
     LIMIT 100;
    EXIT WHEN l_coll.count = 0;

    FORALL i IN l_coll.FIRST .. l_coll.LAST
      INSERT INTO some_table( key_column, val_column )
        VALUES( l_coll(i).key, l_coll(i).val );
  END LOOP;
END;
```

Comment: Wouldn't it be better to BULK COLLECT the results and then insert them using FORALL in one go?

Comment: @Ollie - It would absolutely be more efficient.  I was going for simplicity rather than performance.  But I took your suggestion and posted an example using `BULK COLLECT`